# Azure SDK 1.8 Kills VS2010 Configuration Switching

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, azure-sdk-.net

Ever since upgrading to Azure SDK 1.8 we have been consistently having extremely long delays when switching between build configurations in VS2010. It can take several minutes to switch between a debug and release build. We also see the VS window minimize itself and maximize itself at times during the switch.

This happens 100% of the time on every machine that has been upgraded all Windows 7. We performed the manual install as per the instructions on this page: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35448

Anyone else seeing this?

Comment: Why not upgrade to VS2012?  Since 1.8 SDK targets .Net 4.5 and Server 2012 OS Family it only makes sense to upgrade.

Comment: Why not? It's disruptive. We don't need any new VS features. The functionality we are after is supported in VS 2010. It's very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing the latest "Windows Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2010 SP1) - 2.1" through the Web Platform Installer? I think it should clear those issues.

Here is a direct link to the Microsoft Download page as well:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=39708

Comment: Yes, this appears to eliminate the minimize/maximize of VS during configuration switching, as well as at other times we found it happening, like when a context menu is selected from the Solution Explorer. However I have still seen the behavior during another long running operation, and configuration switching still takes far too long.

Comment: Spoke too soon. It's not as frequent, but the problem still happens - even on configuration switching.